# can't change some nfs options

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, nfs

Im not able to change NFS mount options rsize, wsize and timeo from the default. My /etc/fstab has this entry

> 192.168.10.10:/volume1/Containers /mnt/circe  nfs      defaults    0       0

This is fine

> mount -t nfs -vo remount,rsize=131072 /mnt/circe

This gives me "invalid argument"

> mount -t nfs -vo remount,rsize=32768 /mnt/circe

Kernel: 4.15.0-111-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Console: tty 2 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
mount.nfs: (linux nfs-utils 1.3.3)

Comment: Does it work from the get go, i.e. mounting with this exact option?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov if it add the rsize=32768 option to /etc/fstab and do systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart mnt-circe.mount, mountstats shows the new rsize value

Comment: In my experience `-o remount,new_options` doesn't always work. I've learnt to deal with it.

Comment: i think i can live with this